# How to split a text / string with pattern of upper case letters?

Tags: r, regex, string, split, text-mining

I’m looking to Split a text according to each interlocutor.

The original text has this form:

> this is a speech text. FIRST PERSON: hi all, thank you for coming.
> SECOND PERSON: thank you for inviting us. TERCER PERSONA QUE SE LLAMA
> PEDRO: soy de acuerdo. CUARTA PERSONA (JOHN): Hi. How are you

I’m searching for a final result like this:

first column: FIRST PERSON  |SECOND PERSON | TERCER PERSONA QUE SE LLAMA PEDRO | CUARTA PERSONA (JOHN)

second column: hi all, thank you for coming | thank you for inviting us
|   soy de acuerdo |    Hi. How are you

The final result can also be in other format or reshaped.

The Pattern to split is one or more Upper Word and a ":", but one difficulty is that the pattern in capital letters can have optional characters like: ():,;

In fact the original text that I am searching to split is this one:
https://lopezobrador.org.mx/2021/01/14/version-estenografica-de-la-conferencia-de-prensa-matutina-del-presidente-andres-manuel-lopez-obrador-458/

I have tried different things using stringr rebus and qdap.
First trying this pattern:

```
pattern_mayusc <- UPPER %R% one_or_more(UPPER) %R% optional(") ") %R% ":"
```

Following I tried to extract a vector with the name of each interlocutor to use them as pattern next:

```
mayuscula<-sapply(str_extract_all(text, ".([A-Z]+:)"), paste, collapse= ' ')
```

I am close to obtain what I desire but cannot achieve it. Anyone to help me?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `strsplit` on a pattern that matches either `:` preceded by a sequence of words with any upper case letters `\p{Lu}`, spaces (`\s`) and parentheses (and more if you need), or (`|`) the space, followed by the same sequence. We want the first `el`ement from the resulting list and cleaned with `trimws`. The result is an alternating pattern of speaker and text, which we can easily convert into a two-column `matrix` by row.

```
pat <- r"{(?>\p{Lu}+?\s?)+\(?\p{Lu}+\)?\K(:)|(?<!\w)(\s)(?=\p{Lu}{2,})}"
# pat <- "(?>\\p{Lu}+?\\s?)+\\(?\\p{Lu}+\\)?\\K(:)|(?<!\\w)(\\s)(?=\\p{Lu}{2,})"  ## for R < 4.0.0

tmp <- trimws(el(strsplit(x, pat, perl=TRUE)))[-1]
res <- matrix(tmp, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
res
#      [,1]                                 [,2]                           
# [1,] "FIRST PERSON"                       "hi all, thank you for coming."
# [2,] "SECOND PERSON"                      "thank you for inviting us."   
# [3,] "TERCER PERSONA QUE SE LLAMA ANDRÉS" "soy de acuerdo."              
# [4,] "CUARTA PERSONA (JOHN)"              "Hi. How are you?"             
# [5,] "ANDRÉS"                             "Hola buenos días!"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5O8gh3/3)

---

*Data:*

```
x <- "this is a speech text. FIRST PERSON: hi all, thank you for coming. SECOND PERSON: thank you for inviting us. TERCER PERSONA QUE SE LLAMA ANDRÉS: soy de: acuerdo. CUARTA PERSONA (JOHN): Hi. How are you? ANDRÉS: Hola buenos días!"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply.  
I´m debuting in regular expressions so sorry for the additional questions, but what represent the **r** at the beginning of the pattern?  
I failed to generate the pattern.  
Two error are showing up, the first one is that R tell me “unexpected token” on this line and the second one is when I try to run the line: Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""{\b[A-Z\s"  
Hope you can help me to solve my doubts,
Thanks again

Comment: @thibplass  `r"(...)"` is actually a raw string which is available since [R 4.0.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html), probably your version is outdated? You may just use the old notation with escaping backslashes, see edit.

Comment: You're welcome @thibplass ! Case you don't know it yet, there's a nice regex quiz on https://regex101.com/ you might benefit a lot from.

Comment: @thibplass What you want is a "positive lookbehind", but that makes problems due to non-fixed length. Alternatively you may use `\K` though. Please note that I've changed the regex in my answer to also account for accents in the letters, using \\p{Lu} for any upper case letter and now uses `strsplit` at two points so we can save a line.